# trigger not working in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

HTML view part where on every click on prev and next button viewCategory function will work:

```
  <div class="subheader">
            <ul class="categories">
                <li ng-repeat="cat in categoryList" ng-class="{selected: cat.selected}">
                    <a ng-click="viewCategory(cat.name, cat._id)">{{cat.name}}</a>
                </li>
                <button class="arrow-left" ng-click="prevList($event)"></button>
                <button class="arrow-right" ng-click="nextList($event)"></button>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Controller part:

```
 $scope.nextList = function (e) {
     var ele = e.target;
     $(ele).parent().find('li.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected').triggerHandler('click');
 };
```

Same thing with prev function also
But the trigger is not working ....
Please help me out.. 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to manipulate with DOM into controller. Use directives instead.

Today Agularjs has several plugins like trigger. SO don't reinvent the wheel

On of them: [Slider](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation).

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

at this point you are triggering the click on the li element. Try:

```
$(ele).parent().find('li.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected').find('a').triggerHandler('click');
```